# Express.js route that responds to any subfolder get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set a route in express js that would be triggered by any query that would start with that route Url.

For instance, I want to do the following in an html file:

```
<a href="/article/article1">Article 1</a>
<a href="/article/article2">Article 2</a>
```

and handle the 2 Url by a single route:

```
app.get('/article/*',function(req,res) {
   // do something with req.path
}
```

I know static does that so there should be a way. I want to do this without using query parameters, because urls without query parameters feel more static, and I want to give the users this impression that the page will always work.

Is there something to do that?

Comment: Ah, crap, just after posting, I found out the regex thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out

```
app.get('/article/*',function(req,res) {
   // do something with req.path
}
```

works fine...